# looking for objective c NSList-like options, (i know it's been asked here before), what example could you provide?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, properties

here's what i'm trying to convert to objective c from c#:

```
public class Television
{
     public string Name {get; set};
     public bool isOn {get; set};
     public int channelNum {get; set};
     public string channelName {get; set};
}
```

let's say the television fairy has been to my house, and i don't know how many televisions are in there.  or, i want to make this code reusable and since everyone has a different amount of televisions in their households, i want to make this a different number at every runtime.

```
 public List<Television> TVs = new List<Television>(4);
```

when i want to i can say:

```
 TVs[3].channelNum = 34;
```

1. in objective c, how would you put this in an array/dictionary(hashtable)? can you give me an example?
2. if i created a new object every time a new Television is put in the house, and accessed its properties, is this more efficient on memory than a list class would be?  it seems like a list would be easier than creating 4 array sets, wouldn't it?
3. could someone give me an example of how this would be used if i called

   Television TVs = [[Television alloc]init];

   and used properties instead?
4. could i use television objects in an nsmutablearray, and just pull them out to access their properties when i need them, or when they change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just something to give you an idea (though it's not very lovely code)...

```
@interface Television : NSObject {
@private
    NSString *name;
    BOOL isOn;
    int channelNumber;
    NSString *channelName;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isOn) BOOL on;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int channelNumber;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* channelName;
@end
```

Implemenation

```
@implementation Television
@synthesize name, on=isOn, channelNumber, channelName;
@end
```

Usage

```
Television *tv1 = [[[Television alloc] init] autorelease];
tv1.name = @"TV Name";
tv1.on = YES;
tv1.channelNumber = 236;
tv1.channelName = "Channel 236";

// create a mutable array to use as a list
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

// add tv1 to the array
[array addObject:tv1];

// add another one
[array addObject:[[[Television alloc] init] autorelease]];
[array objectAtIndex:1].name = @"Another name";
```

Comment: You should likely add: wtf, I can't create newlines in a comment? ugh, you should add a - (void)dealloc { method where you do [name release]; [channelName release]; [super dealloc];

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what you mean in your point number 2 (if you have a variable collection of items you need to manage and a mutable array will do, just use a mutable array - ie, avoid premature optimization), but for the rest, it's pretty straightforward:

See [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSMutableArray * televisions = [NSMutableArray array];
Television * thisTV = [[Television alloc] init];
[televisions addObject:thisTV];
[thisTV release];

// ...

[[televisions objectAtIndex:0] setChannelNumber:34];
```

Or [NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSMutableDictionary * televisionsByRoomName = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
Television * thisTV = [[Television alloc] init];
[televisionsByRoomName setObject:thisTV forKey:@"livingroom"];
[thisTV release];
// ...
[[televisionsByRoomName objectForKey:@"livingroom"] setChannelNumber:34];
```

All this and more can be yours for the low, low price of reading the [Collections Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html) which is referenced in a number of places in the introductory conceptual Cocoa documentation.